# My script runs for too long. Is it possible I have too many if-statements nested?

Tags: php, if-statement, directory

I'm new to programming and I'm having to teach myself. But, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this project. This project is for myself, to make shortcuts in PHP so I don't have to program so many lines of code; when I program, sometimes I use the same 20 lines for different applications.

Here is my script:

```
function writeDir($directory = null, $link = null, $exception = null) {
    if (!isset($directory)) {
        $directory = './';
    }
    if (!isset($link)) {
        $link = false;
    }
    if (!isset($exception)) {
        $exception = null;
    }
    // now...
    if ($link==true&&$exception!=null) { // do a link and exception(s)
        $directoryList = scandir($directory); // get an array of all directory items
        $directoryLength = count($directoryList); // count $directoryList array length
        if (is_string($exception)) { // if one (1) exception
            for ($i=2; $i<$directoryLength; $i++) { // cycle through all directory items
                if ($directoryList[$i] == $exception) { // if we hit that one (1) exception
                    echo ''; // do nothing
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="' . $directoryList[$i] . '"> ' . $directoryList[$i] . ' </a><br />' . "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        if (is_array($exception)) { // if multiple exceptions
            $exceptionList = count($exception); // count $exception array length
            for ($i=2; $i<$directoryList; $i++) { // cycle through all directory items
                for ($j=0; $j<$exceptionList; $j++) { // cycle through all exceptions
                    if ($directoryList[$i] == $exceptionList[$j]) { // if we hit one of the multiple exceptions
                        echo ''; // do nothing
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href="' . $directoryList[$i] . '"> ' . $directoryList[$i] . ' </a><br />' . "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($link==true&&$exception==null) {
        $directoryList = scandir($directory);
        $directoryLength = count($directoryList);
        for ($i=2; $i<$directoryLength; $i++) {
            echo '<a href="' . $directoryList[$i] . '"> ' . $directoryList[$i] . ' </a><br />' . "\n";
        }
    }
    if ($link==false&&$exception!=null) { // do only exception(s) without links
        $directoryList = scandir($directory); // get an array of all directory items
        $directoryLength = count($directoryList); // count $directoryList array length
        if (is_string($exception)) { // if one (1) exception
            for ($i=2; $i<$directoryLength; $i++) { // cycle through all directory items
                if ($directoryList[$i] == $exception) { // if we hit that one (1) exception
                    echo ''; // do nothing
                } else {
                    echo $directoryList[$i] . '<br />' . "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        if (is_array($exception)) { // if multiple exceptions
            $exceptionList = count($exception); // count $exception array length
            for ($i=2; $i<$directoryList; $i++) {
                for ($j=0; $j<$exceptionList; $j++) {
                    if ($directoryList[$i] == $exceptionList[$j]) {
                        echo '';
                    } else {
                        echo $directoryList[$i] . '<br />' . "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($link==false&&$exception==null) {
        $directoryList = scandir($directory);
        $directoryLength = count($directoryList);
        for ($i=2; $i<$directoryLength; $i++) {
            echo $directoryList[$i] . '<br />' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I know it looks like a lot. But, I'm trying to make my life simpler when programming.

Basically, the syntax for this when called in a PHP file is:

`writeDir(); // at the very least` :OR: `writeDir('./', true, 'index.php');`

The second one writes files in the current directory with corresponding links to them, but skips over the index.php file.

The third (3rd) argument can be either a single omitted page (as a string) or an array of multiple omitted pages. Or, at least that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Of course an include to this source file would be required on all pages I use it for. Before, when IT WAS working, I could only format the list of directory items with the exclusion of one (1) file. So, I tried to allow for an array of files as well. Now, it loads for ever. I finally had to use a `set_time_limit()` function to quit the script.

Now, one last thing. When I used the `set_time_limit()` function, it displayed my directory items, but for some reason two (2) of everything... What have I done wrong?

Are there too many if-statements, or have I overlooked something? Should I just start over?

I've only programmed (unprofessionally) for about 5 years so I don't really know what it is I'm doing. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Hope I've given enough information and details.

JDot

P.S.
Anybody who wants to use this script is more than welcome to (if it's even worth using).

Comment: `for ($i=2; $i<$directoryList; $i++) { ` - that doesn't look right, because `$directoryList` is an array.

Comment: You do know that Apache does this for you right?

Comment: It is good that you know about code re-use and learn the intricacies about a language. I would recommended though that you look at classes and objects, which is a very good way of reusing code.

Comment: HOT DOG! @Jack, you are so right! I totally missed that. Thank you man, you're awesome, I'll see if that fixes my problem.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I'm not sure if I have access to Apache, or even where to start with it, but I'm interested in doing some research on it now. Thank you.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, I originally thought about writing it with objects and/or classes, but decided since I still know so little about it, it would be easier this way. If fixing the error Jack pointed out doesn't work, I may have to try that. Thank you.

Comment: Learning about classes and objects is a bit of work, but handling the kind of including system you propose, is also a lot of work, especially in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

use esle if

```
if($a==1)
{
echo $a;
}
elseif($b==1)
{
echo $b;
}
else
{
echo "c";
}
```

and there is ternary operator fo single if else statement: learn it